# 25 reputation bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

I have seen an answer which "*has been awarded bounties worth 25 reputation by Community*".

But according to the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), the minimum reputation is 50.

Then, how is it possible?

Comment: In the linked faq see under "What is automatic awarding?": *if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded **half the bounty amount*** (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where a bounty is not awarded by its creator it is awarded automatically.  In this case only half the amount is awarded.

This is covered withing the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> What is automatic awarding?
>
> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the
>   bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be
>   awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period,
>   that answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty
>   period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> **Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is
>   awarded half the bounty amount**. The criteria for an answer to be
>   eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores
>   are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any
>   answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Answer (score 3):

If the person who started the bounty doesn't award it themselves, under some conditions the system will award it - when that happens, half the reputation is awarded.

So, this happened with a 50 rep bounty.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for details.